# How to add Decimal places after formatting to 1000 seperator

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a number, 123456789.998, with this I need to format to 1000 separator and then make it fixed to 2 decimal places. even if it is .00, I need to show as .00. I tried and I could it achieve it. Can you help me with this?

```
var x= 123456789.998
var fixed = Number(x).toFixed(2);
var format = Number(fixed).toLocaleString();
alert(format);
```

I want the result as 12345679.00, but I am getting 12345679

Comment: You can't force the `Number` type to carry redundant decimal places. You'll need to store the value as a string if you want to preserve the trailing `.00`

Comment: Can you please help me with a example

Comment: Pass an object with `minimumFractionDigits: 2` as the 2nd arg to `toLocaleString` (`undefined` as first arg)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Intl` `NumberFormat` with `style` set to `"decimal"`, `minimumFractionDigits` and `maximumFractionDigits` set to `2` and `useGrouping` set to `false`.

Given input `123456789.998` the result will be `123456790.00` not `12345679.00`

```js
let x = 123456789.998;

const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat("en-US", {
  style: "decimal",
  minimumFractionDigits: 2,
  maximumFractionDigits: 2,
  useGrouping: false
});

let n = formatter.format(x);

console.log(n);
```

Comment: If I'm understanding "with this I need to format to 1000 separator " correctly, then `useGrouping: true` might be a better fit

Comment: @DacreDenny OP's expected output does not contain comma `,` characters _"I want the result as 12345679.00"_. Which, also,  is not the correct result for the input decimal.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I need it with seperator. Sorry I forgot to mention in question

Comment: @InduVelayutham Set `useGrouping` to `true` or omit the property from the object passed to `NumberFormat`, where the default result will include separator(s).

Comment: Yes I did it, its fine. Thank you so much

Comment: @DacreDenny can you please help me with adding $ with this

Comment: You mean prefixing the formatted number with a `$` sign?

Comment: @InduVelayutham The original question does not ask for a currency prefix. You can use `{
  style: "currency",
  currency: "USD",
  minimumFractionDigits: 2,
  maximumFractionDigits: 2,
  useGrouping: false
}` to format the return value to `USD` with `$` prefix.

Comment: Yes I did'nt, but now that needs to be included, so asking again

Comment: @InduVelayutham Have you read the previous comment? `new Intl.NumberFormat("en-US", {
  style: "currency",
  currency: "USD",
  minimumFractionDigits: 2,
  maximumFractionDigits: 2,
  useGrouping: false
}).format(123456789.998) // $123456790.00`

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for:

```
var num = Number(123456789.998); // if you wish to round up
var num = Math.floor(123456789.998); // if you wish to truncate after decimal
var n = num.toFixed(2);
alert(n);
```

Comment: CAn you help me with this fiddle   http://jsfiddle.net/indhu_velayutham/59j4nskw/4/

Comment: @InduVelayutham will try :-)

Comment: @InduVelayutham This is my fix...: Just replace Number with Math.floor as I suggested


```    var tmp3 = Math.floor(tmp).toLocaleString("en-US", { currency:"USD", minimumFractionDigits: 2});
```

Comment: @InduVelayutham here is jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/site2goal/5e136p8y/1/